# Domain working fine with http:// but not working with www

Tags: dns, web

I have purchased a domain working fine with http://example.com but with www.example.com its redirect to (example.com/www.example.com) what is the solution that it also work with www.example.com as http://example.com

Comment: You need to point an `A-Record` to your IP in the DNS Settings of your Domain Registrar. Point the host `www` to the IP of your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In htaccess just change this and problem solved

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```